# Kohana ORM get one record in many-to-many relationship

Tags: orm, kohana, kohana-orm

I've got two tables (items / tags). Item has and belongs to many tags - tag has and belongs to many items.

It's no problem for me to fetch all related tags like:

```
$item = ORM::factory('item', 4);
foreach($item->tags as $tag){....}
```

But how can i fetch only one... and maybe a specific one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you know which one you want?  If you have criteria for the one you want, you should load the tag using its own ORM methods, not through the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kohana 3 you can do this:

```
$item = ORM::factory('item', 4);
$tag = $item->tags->where('somevalue','=',$value)->find();
if($tag->loaded()) {...}
```

Inside `where()` you put the condition you want.

**Edit:**

I did a little research and in Kohana 2.3.x the `where` syntax is different, instead of `where('somevalue', '=', $value)` you should write `where('somevalue', $value)`. Or `where('somevalue >', $value)`, `where('somevalue !=', $value)`, etc.

Comment: thank you for your help. however i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong but it gives me following error message. it seems the tables are not inner joined. "There was an SQL error: Unknown column 'item_id' in 'where clause' - SELECT `tags`.* FROM (`tags`) WHERE `item_id` = '=' ORDER BY `tags`.`name` ASC LIMIT 0, 1" i'm using btw. kohana v2.3.4

Comment: Maybe it was my mistake, I thought that tag `belongs_to` item. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: do you happen to know how to do this in kohana 2.3.x?

Comment: still the error i mentioned above: There was an SQL error: Unknown column 'item_id' in 'where clause' - SELECT tags.* FROM (tags) WHERE item_id  = '=' ORDER BY tags.name ASC LIMIT 0, 1"

Comment: Maybe you are calling `where('somevalue', '=', $value)` instead of `where('somevalue', $value)`. Check my edit.